# Results on the same page as the search form php

Tags: php, wordpress

How can i echo the results in the same page as the search form is (wordpress)?(i`m newbie)

```
   <form action="" id="searchform" method="POST">
<input name="searchquery" type="text" placeholder="Nume, spital" size="30" maxlength="40">
        <select name="filter">
            <option value="ALL">Toate judetele</option>
            <option value="AB">Alba</option>    
        </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Cauta">
     </form>
```

the php code

```
 global $wpdb;

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");

$search = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['searchquery']));
if($_POST['filter'] == "ALL"){
$sqlCommand = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wp_doctors` WHERE `name` LIKE '%searchquery%'");
} else if($_POST['filter'] == "AB"){ $sqlCommand = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wp_doctors` WHERE `name` LIKE '%searchquery%' AND `city`= 'Alba'   ");
} //more if`s, i just cuted for example

foreach ( $sqlCommand as $result) 
{
    echo $result->id;
    echo $result->name;
    echo $result->spec;
}
```

and if i`m using  at the form action atribute it will take me to the index page. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try putting in the form action :

```
action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>"
```

In order to test if you are not being redirected by wordpress, try this
in your php code:

```
if(isset($_POST)){
 var_dump($_POST);
}
```

In this way you can clear out if the page is posting right and if you are being
redirected somewhere by wordpress.

Comment: Great answer. Not sure about WordPress but leaving `action` attribute altogether, by default, makes the form post to the same page it is on.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it will post to the same page but setting action explicitly would show, in html source code , where it will post. I think it is clearer that way. Thansk

Comment: After i followed your steps it shows right under the form  "array(0) { }" ...any help?

Comment: Ok.Let's give it another try as it is impossible for $_POST to be empty after submitting to the same page. Add die(); after the var_dump so the code is stopped and you remain in the same page. I think the problem is redirection. If it shows the data with the die function my guess is right

Comment: It reedirect me to the index again and the array its still 0